# What is maximum range of voltage measurement?

Tags: signal

Another 'Basic EE' question here (from a mathematician).  Being rather ignorant of the matter - I would hazard to guess that there is some physical limit to the range of voltages that can be practically measured in an electrical circuit.  Would anyone know what that limit might be?

The terms 'practical' and 'electrical circuit' are meant to imply the context of an average consumer electronic device: ie computer/toaster/stereo/radio/etc.

For example: is \$-2^{100}\$V to \$+2^{100}\$V a range of voltage that can be accurately read?  (I'm assuming not but...)

Comment: Mmmh, the question is a bit ambiguous. Do you consider an electrical pipeline an electric circuit? Because technically it is!

Comment: Please define _practically_ and _electrical circuit_.

Comment: As a gross simplification, multimeters go to 1000 V. After that is gets more tricky. It's quasi transferable to other areas.

Comment: In reality for direct measurement, it's the limit of the insulation barriers of the devices.  Fowler's work (nobel work if I recall) will give you the limits for barriers in the mathematical sense.   Winny's comment is the most practical.   Almost no one measures high voltages directly.

Comment: Just to be sure: do you mean voltages that are (o may be) *present* in a circuit, or *voltages that can be easily measured*. In the latter case, the comment of @winny gives you the right answer (as a ballpark figure). If the case is the former, the thing gets more tricky.

Comment: Insulation breakdown voltage (including the ionization voltage of air) sets the upper limit on the order of 1kV to 10kV. Thermal effects set the practical lower limit on the order of tens of microVolts. So maybe a dynamic range of around 10 orders of magnitude.

Comment: I have a high-voltage probe from my TV repair days that is good to 30,000 volts (25" picture tubes needed 25,000 volts inside).

Comment: High voltage power transmission, particle accelerators, and van de graff generators routinely use voltages in the 100s of kV to a few MV range (at radically different currents!).  Lightning can be over 100 megavolts.  Those are the highest things I know of, but there is no hard upper limit.  Measuring those voltages is... hard.

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting question and I've often wondered if any other technology works over such a wide range.

> I would hazard to guess that there is some physical limit to the range of voltages that can be practically measured in an electrical circuit.

Except maybe for extreme natural phenomena, the upper voltage limit will be for measurement of man-made voltages. The electrical power distribution industry uses voltages of up to a million volts for long-distance DC transmission systems. Since they monitor the line voltage readings at 1 MV are routinely done. The labs testing the insulation for such systems will have to generate voltages far in excess and will measure the voltages generated.

[image]

*Figure 1. For ultra-high voltage measurements your multi-meter probes aren't going to be enough. Source: [HF-Instruments](http://hf-instruments.com/en/products/uhv).*

For low voltage measurements the subject is more tricky due to noise. Kiethley's [Low Level Handbook](http://www.tek.com/sites/tek.com/files/media/document/resources/LowLevelHandbook_7Ed.pdf) is an excellent read on the subject.

[image]

*Figure 2. Voltage measurement and instrument types. White is possible, grey is tricky and black is impossible.*

> The theoretical limit of sensitivity in any measurement is determined by
>   the noise generated by the resistances present in the circuit. As discussed
>   in Sections 2.6.5 and 3.2.6, voltage noise is proportional to the square root
>   of the resistance, bandwidth, and absolute temperature.
>   Figure 1-2 shows theoretical voltage measurement limits at room temperature (300K) with a response time of 0.1 second to ten seconds. Note that high source resistance limits the theoretical sensitivity of the voltage measurement. Although
>   it’s certainly possible to measure a 1μV signal that has a 1
>   Ω
>   source resistance, it’s not possible to measure that same 1μV signal level from a 1TΩ
>   source. Even with a much lower 1MΩ
>   source resistance, a 1μV measurement is near theoretical limits, so it would be very difficult to make using
>   an ordinary DMM.

Answer (score 0):

Fluke (a maker of voltmeters) offers handheld meter probes for 6 kV, 15 kV, 40 kV.   There are also electrostatic voltmeters (rarely seen outside laboratories) that can go
significantly higher.  Ben Franklin could have used a pith-ball electroscope
to do measurements in this range...

High voltages generally are avoided, of course.  Automobile spark coils, electron microscopes, X-ray machines might have high internal
voltages, but one wouldn't normally open them up and apply a voltmeter.

One physical limit is corona discharge in air (St. Elmo's fire).  Insulation 
breakdown of other materials can also be a problem, but a HV wire will usually be very fat, or have thick insulation, because otherwise it'd break the chemical bonds of
atmospheric gases, making ions and ozone and generally corroding everything
in sight.

Answer (score 0):

**What do you consider practical? Let's look at the limits of what's possible**.

Some of the other answers here have given good examples of high and low voltages which are practical to measure, but I's like to give a couple of examples which push the limits a bit further. At the end of the day, most the examples people have given are mostly for off-the-shelf measurement equipment, so they are driven by the limits of what there is a market for.  If there is no point trying to measure voltages below a nanovolt because of thermal noise, no-one will try to make a multimeter to do that. But if you take away thermal noise, you can make sub-nanovolt measurements.  Which leads me on to my first example:

**SQUID resistance bridge: 100fV = 1E-13V**
Here's part of a circuit I built as during my PhD.  We wanted to measure the resistance of small samples in a dilution refrigerator, at 0.01 degrees above absolute zero.  We couldn't pass big currents through the samples or they heat up, so we needed a very accurate voltage measurement system. Here it is:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOkYnf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The minimum voltage you can measure with this circuit depends on the thermal noise and the noise current in the SQUID. But by adjusting the resistance of Rref, you can get rid of the SQUID noise and increase the thermal noise.  So in reality, you're only limited by the thermal noise - if you move this circuit into a nuclear demag refrigerator, you'll get even better performance - but as far as I know that has never been done.

**Lightning: >100MV = 1E8V**

The largest man-made voltages in various physics labs come short of what nature can achieve, so if we want to see a big voltage measurement, we should look at the research groups who study lightning. This one's outside my area of expertise, but a quick look on google suggests 120MV lightning strikes have been recorded. I can't find how that was measured, but I can hazard a guess: one (slightly crude) way to measure voltage is to measure how far a spark travels through air. We know that air undergoes dielectric breakdown once the electric field reaches 3MV/m. So if the lightning bolt travels 40m through air, then the potential difference was 120MV before the discharge. You might argue that isn't really a voltage measurement as such, in which case the HVDC transmission line measurement kit in Transistor's answer is probably pretty close, at a bit over 1MV.

**Aside**
One of the other answer comments that the dynamic range is very large, and he wonders if there is anything we can measure with a higher range.  The range from my two examples is about 10^21. But one thing we can measure better is time, we can measure atomic line transitions as short as 10^-17 seconds indirectly by spectroscopy, and the age of the universe as 10^16 seconds. That gives a total range of 10^33.